# Oracle Apex: step by step approach to creating radio buttons in interactive report

Tags: oracle, radio-button, oracle-apex

Is there a good visual tutorial that takes through the various steps on how to create radio buttons in Apex 4.2? This tutorial [Creating a Form in APEX to set Variables in a Query for an Interactive Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798449/creating-a-form-in-apex-to-set-variables-in-a-query-for-an-interactive-report)  helped me in creating forms and I’m looking for a similar one.

Within my application, I would like to add a radio button to each row of my interactive report which when selected would take the user to another report combining different tables?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean radio buttons?  Sounds like you rather want a link on each row to take you to a another report page?

Comment: @TonyAndrews Yes I do mean radio buttons. Is a row link possible? 

The reason why I want radio buttons is because when the user selects a customer's name and booing order number from the interactive report, after their details are collected from a from, it should take them to another report where it should show their address details and their booking order details. 

I'm new to apex so any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes a link is certainly possible - just edit the report column and fill in the Column Link properties.  By radio buttons, do you mean use a radio buttons to select the row before linking off to another page by clicking on a button or link elsewhere on the page?  That is also possible, though not as easy as just creating a column link.

Comment: I tell you what - as we seem to have a time zone difference, I'll write an answer showing both methods...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could either use a column link to select the record and navigate to another page, or a radio button and a page button/link to do it.  I'll demonstrate both using a simple report on the DEPT table.

**Method 1: radio button**

For the radio button we can add an additional column to the report using the `apex_item.radiogroup` function to create a radio button whose value is the DEPTNO:

[image: Report SQL statement]

By default, the HTML of the radiogroup will be escaped for security reasons, which is not what you want but illustrates what it is doing quite nicely:

[image: Report]

We can fix that by changing the column property to "Standard Report Column":

[image: Changing column type]

Now we see:

[image: Report after fix]

Clicking on the radio button on any row selects it and deselects the buttons on other rows.

To navigate to another page with the selected row we need a button to submit the page with a special request:

[image]

[image]

When clicked, that button will submit the page with a Request value of "SELECT" (the button name I chose).  So we can write an on-submit page process to fire when the request is "SELECT", find out which radio button has been selected (if any) and save the selected DEPTNO to a hidden item called say P34_DEPTNO.  We find out which button by looking at the APEX array `apex_application.g_f01` which we chose by passing `1` as the first parameter to `apex_item.radiogroup`:

```
if apex_application.g_f01.count > 0 then
   -- Array has been populated i.e. user chose a value
   :p34_deptno := apex_application.g_f01(1);
else 
   -- Array has not been populated i.e. user did not choose a value
   :p34_deptno := null;
end if;
```

Then we can define a branch that navigates to the new page if (a) request = 'SELECT' and (b) P34_DEPTNO is not null.

[image]

And that's it.  Quite a lot of work, but if that's the requirement that will do it.

**Method 2: column link**

The simpler way is to dispense with the radio buttons and just make one of the report columns into a link:

[image]

This turns the column (I chose DNAME) into a link that navigates to the new page taking the selected DEPTNO value with it:

[image]

That's it!  No hidden item, no button, no page process, no branch...

Comment: My goodness! Thank you so much! This is by far the best tutorial ever. Thank you for including the print screens. Very very helpful. Definitely giving it a go now. Thanks again! This is exactly what I want my report to do too. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

For Apex 5 you have to change "Escape special characters" to "No" instead of changing the column property to "Standard Report Column":

[image]