# Oracle Apex 19.2 - Create Radio Buttons in Classic Report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is there a good visual tutorial that takes through the various steps on how to create radio buttons in Apex 19.2? [This tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28601892/oracle-apex-step-by-step-approach-to-creating-radio-buttons-in-interactive-repo) Creating a Classic Report having radio button on each row helped me and I’m looking for a similar one..

In my case, I would like to add a radio button to each row of my classic report which when selected would add some of the informations selected by the radio button in a text field in the same page.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: This one comes to mind, but any time I see "radio buttons" and "report", I think of other solutions http://vincentdeelen.blogspot.com.au/2013/08/using-radio-buttons-in-apex-report.html

Comment: Rafrafii, do you still need help with this? If so, please set up an example on apex.oracle.com. Get it as far as you can and then provide developer credentials to your workspace (be careful there's nothing sensitive in there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Sample Reporting application on your APEX instance (preferably on apex.oracle.com as Dan suggested).

Navigate to the Classic Report page.

Change the query to the report to the following:

```
select rowid,
       ID,
       PROJECT,
       TASK_NAME,
       START_DATE,
       END_DATE,
       STATUS,
       ASSIGNED_TO,
       COST,
       BUDGET,
       apex_item.radiogroup(1,TASK_NAME) ACTION
from EBA_DEMO_IR_PROJECTS
where (nvl(:P3_STATUS,'0') = '0' or :P3_STATUS = status)
```

Note the added column "ACTION" which consists of the apex_item.radiogroup with TASK_NAME value. Let's assume that this is the value that you want to pass to another page item.

Open that column's attribute under Page Designer and disable "Escape special characters" attribute and add a CSS Class (e.g. mycolumn)

Create a Page Item (e.g. **P3_NEW**).

Now add the following Dynamic Action

- Event > Click
- Selection Type > jQuery Selector
- jQuery Selector > #classic_report .mycolumn input

[image]

Your true action will be of the type **Set Value** and the **Set Type** is **JavaScript Expression** with the following code:

```
this.triggeringElement.value
```

Your affected element is **P3_NEW** and disable **Fire on Initialization**

[image]