# How to get multiple selected checkbox values in page item and submit on next page

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

[image: select the checkbox and the value(food_received_uid)should display in the page item and submit process]

When checkbox is selected the selected row's id(food_received_uid) should display in the page item after the page item draws the value from checkbox when submit button is pressed the value in the page item should go to next page. In that second page there is a form where the id should fill there.

[image: select the checkbox and the value(food_received_uid)should display in the page item and submit process]

Comment: Although images can be helpful, the code is what we can work with, Abinesh. How about coming up with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us that shows what you want in code, what you've tried, what went wrong - anything like that?

Comment: I am not sure sir i just did the outline of the work I need to know how to process the function could u suggest me what to do help me fix this out .....I am just a beginner

Comment: Hi Abinesh, I think what you want to achieve it selecting a row on your report. After the row has been selected you want to populate the page item "Food Received Uid" with the value of the column "food_received_uid" from the same selected row. Later on you want to pass the value of the page item to a second page.

Comment: May I suggest that you use an Interactive Grid instead? .. let me know if my understanding is correct and please confirm if you can replace the Interactive Report with Interactive Grid.

Comment: I want to create in interactive reprt not in interactive gride and i fixed it thank you for u r helps

Answer (score 0):

You can create a radio button following this approach: [Oracle Apex: step by step approach to creating radio buttons in interactive report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28601892/oracle-apex-step-by-step-approach-to-creating-radio-buttons-in-interactive-repo)

Your column in the query can be: apex_item.radiogroup(1,food_received_uid) test

Add a Static ID for the Radio Button column (e.g. test)
Then a simple Dynamic Action on Change for the following jQuery selector:

```
td [headers="test"] input[type="radio"]
```

Then you can get the value of the radio button by calling the javascript:

```
this.triggeringElement.value;
```